# Restrict occurrence of Line item based on input condition in xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to populate the line item E1EP01 in output structure only if the value of E1EP01/CODE = WK30 and E1EP01/E1EP19/TEXT is not blank , in input file.
I have written below line of codes but E1EP01 is not appearing in Output even if CODE has value equal to WK30 and TEXT is not blank
Can anyone please help me in this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ORDERS05>
         <IDOC>
            <xsl:if test=" ZXX/IDOC/E1EP01/CODE = &apos;WK30&apos; and ZXX/IDOC/E1EP01/E1EP19/TEXT!= &apos; &apos;">
               <xsl:for-each select="E1EP01">
                  <E1EP01>
                     <POSEX>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ZXX/IDOC/E1EP01/POSEX"/>
                     </POSEX>
                  </E1EP01>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
         </IDOC>
      </ORDERS05>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZXX>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <E1EP01 SEGMENT="1">
         <POSEX>00020</POSEX>
         <CODE>WN14</WERKS>
         <E1EP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <Q>001</Q>
            <TEXT>000000000000204034</TEXT>
         </E1EP19>
       </E1EP01>
      <E1EP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <POSEX>00010</POSEX>
        <WERKS>WK30</WERKS>
        <E1EP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <Q>001</Q>
            <TEXT>000000000000205115</TEXT>
        </E1EP19>
      </E1EP01>
   </IDOC>
</ZXX>
```

Comment: This doesn't fit: `<CODE>WN14</WERKS>`

Comment: Hello, I have corrected that thanks but E1EP01 is not yet restricted in output. I am getting E1EP01 even if CODE value is not WK30.

Comment: The test you have now looks for at least one E1EP01 where CODE="WK30" **and** at least one E1EP01 where E1EP19/TEXT is not empty. If you want to test each E1EP01 individually for both conditions, that's something else.

Comment: Yes, I need to test each E1EP01 for the condition and if condition matches then that E1EP01 should appear in output. Could you please give some tips on such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="E1EP01">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ZXX/IDOC/E1EP01">
```

---

Note: you don't need to escape single quotes as `&apos;` in your test expression.

---

### Added:

> I need to test each E1EP01 for the condition and if condition matches
>   then that E1EP01 should appear in output.

Try it this way, then:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ZXX">
    <ORDERS05>
        <IDOC>
            <xsl:for-each select="IDOC/E1EP01[CODE='WK30' and E1EP19/TEXT!='']">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="POSEX"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </IDOC>
    </ORDERS05>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. With this approach, I am getting both the E1EP01 in output even if the value is other than "WK30". Please suggest.

Comment: @A.Sen See the addition to my answer.